# Is there a way to specify who drop table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I met the phenomenon that the table suddenly disappears.
I checked the history of project query, but there is no DELETE TABLE query.
I want to find who (or which service account) did drop the table.
Is there a way to specify who drop table other than project query history?

Added:
I already checked table expiration date, partition expiration date.

Comment: Maybe your dataset has a table expiry setting? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#table-expiration

Comment: thank you for replying. I already checked table expiration date, partition expiration date.
I added this statement in question!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are other optios as well

1. You can check in Activity logs

[image]

2. In more details , you can check logs in Logging.

Use filter in log query

resource.type="bigquery_resource"

protoPayload.methodName = "tableservice.delete"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed replying. This answer helps me a lot.
In my case, there is no suspicious log around the time table deleted.
Next time I meet a similar situation, I"ll check in Activity logs.